# How to call multiple namespaces for soap api call in android?

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

Here following is the applied Api call on Soap UI, which seems perfectly fine (It even works on SoapUI)

[image]

But getting the following exception while working with it.

[image]

Please check the source code written by me. I think this problem should be because of the source code.

[Source Code](http://pastebin.com/1RL8PYLN)

Comment: Instead of pasting screenshots, paste the code...

Comment: @dstronczak I have added the source code. Please check.